# Is there any way to specify intervals between labels on a particular axis using SpreadSheet::WriteExcel?

Tags: excel, perl

I am using Spreadsheet::WriteExcel module and creating column charts based on some data. However, in a few charts I wish to change the interval between x-axis labels. Currently, in some of them it is showing labels alternatively( interval=2). I want to make this interval to be 1 so that all the labels are shown.

Does Spreadsheet::WriteExcel::Chart;
have this functionality?